# How do I convert these headings into questions?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, exam-questions

1. **Sectional Differences Divide The Union**
2. **The Ongoing Debate over Slavery: 1850-1856**
3. **From Compromise to Crisis:1857-1861**

*Thanks for the help guys!*

Comment: "I" is always capitalized, when used to refer oneself.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Please note: We are no translation or proofreading service, but we would be happy to answer any *specific* question you have. But you'll have to do your homework first: Give us the results of you own work, your ideas and what baffles you. Also, some context is always nice: What exactly are you trying to do here - your question is a bit too vague.

Comment: If you are wondering how to edit your question, please check the "Help Center" (click on "help", top right of every page) or read these posts on Meta: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: This question seems more like homework help than a specific English question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really enough context to turn them into meaningful questions. The first two can be made into questions by adding **what is/are**, but without knowing *what you're trying to ask* there's not enough information here to help you.

1. **What were** the Sectional Differences **that** Divided The Union?
2. **What is** the Ongoing Debate over Slavery?